# AngularJS HTTP call takes two minutes while the Rails action only takes 20 seconds, how can I debug this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, performance, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an AngularJS app and there's one page in my application, only one, that is taking 2 minutes to load. It is loading a bit of data, but the data itself is only 700KB and I benchmarked the entire rails action starting from the beginning until right before the render and it only takes 15-20 seconds. But when I look at the actual network call, or I put a timer before the angular http post call and then one in the success, they both show the call taking almost 2 minutes. I can't figure out what's going on between the render and the success on angular that would be causing this extreme time difference. Does anyone know how I could further debug this or possibly know what could be causing this?

The rails action just does a couple big database calls, all optimized, then does some work on the data, then the data (which is already JSONified with to_json) is rendered out.

Rails action ends with `Completed 200 OK in 20458ms (Views: 913.8ms | ActiveRecord: 139.6ms)`

Edit: If I put a limit on my data it's almost instant, so it definitely has to do with the data. But I'm not sure what could be causing the minute and a half disconnect between when the rails action finished and the http post success begins.

Edit2: An ajax call takes an equal amount of time. So there must be an issue with how the data is being parses on the front end, not sure the best way to do this. Since there's an obvious issue between the render and the page getting it.

Comment: Serving assets ? Are you using some quiet_assets gem that may hide some stuff in the console ? Also, it probably has nothing to do with AngularJS

Comment: @CyrilDD Nothing but the layout is served with rails and we don't use any asset pipelining. Everything is served gulped and put into the public directory and served directly, on production that's with nginx, although I guess it is using Thin on my development machine. I'm just not sure where the hangup could be since I see the rails action complete in 20 seconds, then the network call hangs for the rest of the time.

This is the only page on my app that does this which is weird, and when I limit the data on the rails call it's instant. So that is odd.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I mixed the 2 minutes with the 20s of rendering.... 20sec of rendering is still abnormally high for an action (you have only 1 sec of rendering, so what is it doing during the other 19 secs ?). Wha kind of data are we talking about ? Just an array of string or number ? Or more complex/nested data ?

Comment: @CyrilDD It's actually 20 seconds for the entire action. The data queries and work on the data takes about 19 seconds on development and slightly less on production/staging, the actual line of rendering is benchmarking at .27 seconds. It's a `render json: { data1: large_hash, data2: large_hash }, status: 200` and the large hashes have already been `to_json`ed with some limiting :only parameters.

Comment: I will leave that to AngularJS experts then. Maybe the last thing I could say, is that the data is going to be parsed in javascript, so you may actually end up with several MBs of parsed data in memory that needs to be processed and displayed by AngularJS. But it should be able to cope with that. You say when you put a limit on data it's instantaneous. Can you identify a threshold value above which the rendering becomes very slow ?

Comment: @CyrilDD I'm doing some testing now, so far I've found that limiting to 5 returns it in 5.7 seconds. Limit 10 => 20 seconds. Limit 20 => 34 seconds. Limit 30 => goes up to 51 seconds. But again the rails app action finishes in 13 seconds with the limit 30. So there's still a large time difference between when the Rails action ends and the AngularJS success begins.

Comment: @CyrilDD One thing I don't know is if the network tab which I'm monitoring will show only when AngularJS is done parsing it or not, if it doesn't complete until the parse is done then it is possible it's an issue with AngularJS parsing it or how I'm returning it, but I'm just returning it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was somehow the extremely complex hash my old coworker wrote. I think the whole thing was pretty unnecessary so I deleted all 90 lines of code where he built the hash from scratch and instead 3 lines.

I now have the two activerecord queries with the proper includes, and then wrote one render state on those activerecord objects with `as_json` with the proper include and only parameters and the only thing now loads in 25 seconds on development. I can only imagine it'll be faster in production/staging. I don't know why the hashes were so hard to render as json, but calling `as_json` on the active record objects within the render statement completely fixed my issue.

Comment: Are you sure that it was the "rendering" of hashes as JSON that was taking time? More likely, it was the hash itself.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 It was the way rails handles rendering complex pre-jsonified hashes vs jsonifying ActiveRecord objects. The objects I'm returning now are no more complex. I'm not sure if it's javascript or rails which was the bottleneck, it makes more sense that the javascript had a harder time parsing it. Either way it's how rails sent it though.